# an efficient equivalent to numpy isnan or where that looks over a window of N values

Tags: python, numpy, functional-programming

I have an operation I want to do in python on a 1D array with a finite but fairly large explicit stencil -- in other words, the output at [n] depends on the input from [t-N] to [t+N].

My processing code doesn't deal graciously with nan values and an expedient way for me to handle the situation is to substitute a well-behaved input for the nan and overwrite the output with a nan anywhere the output would have been "touched" by a nan.

So in pseudocode with input x and output y I am looking for a function that does this:

```
y = where( is_nan_within_window(x, N), nan, x)
```

Is there an efficient way to do this? A stencil trick perhaps? If not, is there a cheap windowed operation that will amplify the nans in x to the ones that are needed in y so I can use np.where()?

Thanks.

Comment: Dammit, I know there's something that does this. It even handles things like a 2D array where you want to exclude everything a knight's move away from a NaN. Can't remember what it was, though.

Comment: @user2357112: Are you thinking of [ndimage.generic_filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter.html)?

Comment: Possibly. I'm not sure. It's the closest match I've found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `np.where` to find the index of the NaNs, then use `np.add.outer` to include all the neighboring indices:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(100, dtype='float')
x[x % 13 == 0] = np.nan
print(x)        
# [ nan   1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  nan  14.
#   15.  16.  17.  18.  19.  20.  21.  22.  23.  24.  25.  nan  27.  28.  29.
#   30.  31.  32.  33.  34.  35.  36.  37.  38.  nan  40.  41.  42.  43.  44.
#   45.  46.  47.  48.  49.  50.  51.  nan  53.  54.  55.  56.  57.  58.  59.
#   60.  61.  62.  63.  64.  nan  66.  67.  68.  69.  70.  71.  72.  73.  74.
#   75.  76.  77.  nan  79.  80.  81.  82.  83.  84.  85.  86.  87.  88.  89.
#   90.  nan  92.  93.  94.  95.  96.  97.  98.  99.]

N = 2
idx = np.where(np.isnan(x))[0]
shifts = np.arange(-N,N+1)
idx = np.clip(np.add.outer(shifts, idx), 0, len(x)-1).ravel()
y = x.copy()
y[idx] = np.nan
print(y)
```

yields

```
[ nan  nan  nan   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  nan  nan  nan  nan
  nan  16.  17.  18.  19.  20.  21.  22.  23.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  29.
  30.  31.  32.  33.  34.  35.  36.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  42.  43.  44.
  45.  46.  47.  48.  49.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  55.  56.  57.  58.  59.
  60.  61.  62.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  68.  69.  70.  71.  72.  73.  74.
  75.  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  81.  82.  83.  84.  85.  86.  87.  88.  nan
  nan  nan  nan  nan  94.  95.  96.  97.  98.  99.]
```

---

There is also a way to do it with [scipy.ndimage.generic_filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter.html). It is more readable, but much slower for this purpose:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage

x = np.arange(100, dtype='float')
x[x % 13 == 0] = np.nan
print(x)

N = 2
def blank(window):
    return np.nan if np.any(np.isnan(window)) else window[N]
y = ndimage.generic_filter(x, blank, size=(2*N+1,))
print(y)
```

---

Here is a benchmark comparing the first and second methods:

```
def using_generic():
    def blank(window):
        return np.nan if np.any(np.isnan(window)) else window[N]
    y = ndimage.generic_filter(x, blank, size=(2*N+1,))
    return y

def using_where():
    idx = np.where(np.isnan(x))[0]
    shifts = np.arange(-N,N+1)
    idx = np.clip(np.add.outer(shifts, idx), 0, len(x)-1).ravel()
    y = x.copy()
    y[idx] = np.nan
    return y

In [89]: %timeit using_where()
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.1 µs per loop

In [90]: %timeit using_generic()
1000 loops, best of 3: 816 µs per loop
```

Comment: I'm glad you added both variants. I learned something from both. Thanks!